# Convery my UIImageView to a PFFile in SWIFT

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimageview, pffile

I have a UIImageView in my storyboard, and the user can successfully select an image from their phone to place in the ImageView; however, I'm not sure how to get that from the storyboard to Parse.com.

Any code would be much appreciated.  There are lots of tutorials on downloading, but not saving initially.

Comment: You can't save an image view, and the storyboard doesn't matter. You need to get the image data and create the `PFFile`, give that a try.

Comment: so I need to convert the image from the storyboard into NSData? then to a PFFile?

Comment: You said they select an image from the phone, the storyboard has nothing to do with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take the image out of the UIImageView and sage it to a PFFile.

`var file = PFFile(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0))`

Then of course, you can upload the file somewhere you choose.

Comment: thank you for the help!  this worked perfectly.  Now I just need to shrink the size some.  I'll try modifying that 1.0 to 0.5 or something